# How to set a full screen background image in a Windows Phone 8 Pivot App?

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I want to set an image as a full screen background for my Windows Phone 8 Pivot App. Is there any method in XAML to do so? If it exists please help me out and also guide me what are the resolutions for the image, that should be used in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Pivot` control has a `Background` property for that purpose. If you want to have a different image for different resolutions, check out this MSDN resource: [Multi-resolution apps for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206974%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Note that the article is not updated and there is a fourth resolution: 1080p. Use 1080p images instead of 720p images.

Comment: How do we change the background with each pivot element? I mean how to change the full page background whne you swipe to the next pivot?

Comment: Each `PivotItem` has its own background. But what do you mean by "full page background"?

Comment: I think @ShaswatRungta means to get the same functionality as with the Hub/HubSection control. A Hub can have (somehow) a background which, if you scroll between its HubSection controls, is paned, but you never see the full picture, only as much as one section screen size allows. Correct me if I'm wrong.